# How to resume previous activity instead of going to default HOME launcher

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-launcher

I have created a settings activity which will get fired when I press the two volume keys simultaneously. I am invoking this settings activity using an Intent from PhoneWindowManager.java as below,

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.MyApp.Settings.EXT_SETUP");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mContext.startActivity(intnt);
```

I am also running a custom launcher application. While the custom launcher is running, I am able to invoke my settings Activity by pressing the volume buttons.

But the problem is, after exiting the custom settings activity ( by calling finish()), the control is not going to the custom launcher (which is the previous active task). Instead Android is calling home launcher activity which is resulting in going to HOME screen instead of resuming my custom launcher.

I have tried the Intent flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP`. But nothing worked.

Please let me know on how I can invoke the custom launcher after exiting my settings Activity.

Thanks in advance,
Phani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chk this out

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.MyApp.Settings.EXT_SETUP");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
mContext.startActivity(intnt);
```

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);` If set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack.

Comment: @Rhoit, My requirement is different here. I want to clean exit the settings activity and resume my previous launcher activity instead of going to home. This flag is not helping my purpose.

Comment: @phani: In manifest file use `android:parentActivityName`. I think it will serve your purpose

Comment: Still not working. The problem here is that, the setup activity is launched from Android OS, and once the setup activity finishes, there is no previous activity to return to as it is launched from OS. Hence it is falling back to HOME. The key is how to invoke the previous activity that is there in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```