# Android: Previous activity returns on back button press after finish()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have 2 activities. The first activity is the `LogoActivity`. After 3 seconds I start the second activity that is my `MainActivity`.

```
private void startCountDown(int duration, int interval) {
    CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(duration, interval) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            startActivity(MainActivity.class);
            finish();
        }
    };

    mCountDownTimer.start();
}
```

`startActivity(Class mClass)` is a method that I created to start any activity just by giving the class.

Now I am in the `MainActivity`. If I exit by pressing home button and return back I see the `MainActivity`, but if I press back button from `MainActivity` and reopen the app from background the `LogoActivity` show up first.

I dont want the users to see the `LogoActivity` everytime they press back button(button from phone, not activity) from `MainActivity` and restore it from background.

**Why is the `LogoActivity` shown if I called `finish()`?**

Comment: post your manifest xml!

Comment: @JoeFrostick I have changed nothing in my manifest. LogoActivity is my LAUNCHER activity, but I didnt expected it to open again if I called finish().

Comment: I don't know why back return to finish activity but you can disable the back button from your MainActivity...

Comment: Just humour me - want to see if you've set LogoActivity as MainActivity's parent

Comment: @JoeFrostick No I haven't. But my problem is when I press back button from phone, not from the activity that appears when you set a parent for the activity.

Comment: Try : this.finish() OR LogoActivity.finish()

Comment: try handler for this instead of startCountDown

Comment: check if this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141996/android-how-to-override-the-back-button-so-it-doesnt-finish-my-activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press back button, the instance of MainActivity is destroyed.

And then you come back to this task stack again, the LogoActivity is your default Activity so the system creates one instance of it for you.

You can make the MainActivity the default Activity in manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And start LogoActivity in the onCreate method of MainActivity so the user will see LogoActivity first.

After 3 seconds, finish the LogoActivity.

Comment: I tested activity lifecycle and what you said is correct. Would be a good practice to use this method or is there any other alternative?

Comment: Another to to do it is to use one Activity, 2 Fragments.

Comment: 2 fragments doesnt worth the effort, so I will use the first method. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Why is the LogoActivity shown if I called finish()?

The answer is-
When you start your application than your system checks app's ManifestFile to get An activity  whose Intent-filter action and category is set to "android.intent.action.MAIN" and "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" .

This activity is your app's launcher(first) activity.
(I think ,In your case it is LogoActivty).

When you starts your app "Android system" adds this activity in your Activity stack.As you start some other activity that one also add to the top of Activity stack.

On finish an activity it will removed from Activity stack.

whenever you start your app "Android system" traces Activity stack to get top activty.And start your application from that one.

If it found Activity stack empty the system starts your app with your app's launcherActivity.

In your case you finishes both activities.Thus your Activity stack becomes empty and it start you app with LogoActivity.

**SOLUTION**

override onBackPress method in MainActivity and dont call finish. But In this case your Activity will not closed onbackPress.

Or make your MainActivity launcher activity

Comment: Your answer is very good but I already accepted an answer. I choosed to make MainActivity my launcher activity because I will show LogoActivity just at first app start. Thanks for your activity stack explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Because it is different using Back vs Home button. See Android Activity lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

Try overiding `onBackPressed()` method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to control the onBackPressed() method of your activity.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, expand your answer. Explain your solution in more details, provide an example. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use activity attributes in manifest to achieve the same.

"android:finishOnTaskLaunch"

For more please visit http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Always use `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);`

Comment: Why did you just post the same answer to two different questions? This answer is the same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35173592/1987598.

Comment: Because it fixes them both.

Comment: Fair enough. Usually, when the answers to two separate questions are the same, one should be closed as a duplicate of the other.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `Intent` for new activity. Like this.

```
startActivity(new Intent(LogoActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
finish();
```

Instand of only `startActivity(MainActivity.class)`

Comment: I said that ``startActivity(Class mClass)`` is a method I created and contains the Intent. So your answer is irrelevant.